# Using Meteor.call to insert multiple fields, issue

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new to meteor and I'm following the first tutorial (TODO LIST) but using with my own exemple.
So I was able to submit a form into the mongo DB but insecurely, through the client template. Now I'm moving to define the method on a file that can be used for both client and server, using this code - cliente.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const Clientes = new Mongo.Collection('clientes');

Meteor.methods({
  'clientes.insert'(nome, idade,genero,sessao,data,quemPreenche) {
        check(nome, String);
        check(idade, String);
        check(genero, String);
        check(sessao, String);
        check(data, Date);
        check(quemPreenche, String);
        // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
        if (! this.userId) {
          throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
        }

        Clientes.insert({
          nome,
          idade,
          genero,
          sessao,
          data,
          quemPreenche,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          owner: this.userId,
          username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
        });
      },
});
```

And on the client side I'm calling the method like this - novasessao.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Perguntas } from '../api/perguntas.js';
import { Clientes } from '../api/clientes.js';


import './novasessao.html';

Template.novasessao.events({
'keypress form.nova-sessao' : function (event){
    if (event.which === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let dadosclientes = {};
            const target = event.currentTarget;
            const nome = target.nome.value;
            const idade = target.idade.value;
            const genero = target.genero.value;
            const sessao = target.sessao.value;
            const data = target.data.value;
            const quemPreenche = target.quemPreenche.value;
           Meteor.call('clientes.insert',{nome,idade,genero,sessao,data,quemPreenche});
     }
   }
 });
```

The problem is that i can't submit anymore getting the following error:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'clientes.insert' errorClass {message: "Match error: Expected string, got object", path: "", sanitizedError: errorClass, errorType: "Match.Error", stack: "Error↵    at exports.check (http://localhost:3000/…983d07ae9423dd57f5b3c9f92b5593d2952f1b86:3717:25)"} Error
    at exports.check (http://localhost:3000/packages/check.js?hash=63d7478b74cadc04d378bc2266ea8bd1bf6849d8:67:15)
    at DDPCommon.MethodInvocation.clientesInsert (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=cfb80c1b0d41ad6244ac6e6510745a82024f58f6:200:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=bc32a166cd269e06a394f9418e0024d805bab379:3973:25
    at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=e3f53db3be730057fed1a5f709ecd5fc7cae1229:1077:17)
    at Connection.apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=bc32a166cd269e06a394f9418e0024d805bab379:3964:54)
    at Connection.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=bc32a166cd269e06a394f9418e0024d805bab379:3840:17)
    at Object.keypressFormNovaSessao (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=cfb80c1b0d41ad6244ac6e6510745a82024f58f6:139:40)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=983d07ae9423dd57f5b3c9f92b5593d2952f1b86:3718:20
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=983d07ae9423dd57f5b3c9f92b5593d2952f1b86:3687:12)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=983d07ae9423dd57f5b3c9f92b5593d2952f1b86:3717:25)
meteor.js?hash=e3f53db…:930 Error invoking Method 'clientes.insert': Match failed [400]
```

Can anyone help here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save to Mongo you need to give it a JSON object.

Replacing some of your client code:

```
target: event.currentTarget;

let dadosclientes = {
    nome: target.nome.value,
    idade: target.idade.value,
    genero: target.genero.value,
    sessao: target.sessao.value,
    data: target.data.value,
    quemPreenche: target.quemPreenche.value
};
Meteor.call('clientes.insert',dadosclientes);
```

and in the server:

```
  'clientes.insert'(dadosclientes) {
    check(dadosclientes.nome, String);
    check(dadosclientes.idade, String);
    check(dadosclientes.genero, String);
    check(dadosclientes.sessao, String);
    check(dadosclientes.data, Date);
    check(dadosclientes.quemPreenche, String);
    // Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
    if (! this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }

    dadosclientes.createdAt = new Date();
    dadosclientes.owner = this.userId;
    dadosclientes.username = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username;
    Clientes.insert(dadosclientes);
  }
```

Comment: Hi Mikkel, tahnk you. I have replaced but now I get this error: `novasessao.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: target is not defined
    at Object.keypressFormNovaSessao (novasessao.js:16)`. Actually I didn't understand why you replaced const target = event.currentTarget; for target: event.currentTarget;

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are right, use const target = event.currentTarget;

Comment: No problem, but then it throughs another error: `Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'clientes.insert' errorClass {message: "Match error: Expected Date", path: "", sanitizedError: errorClass, errorType: "Match.Error", stack: "Error↵    at exports.check (http://localhost:3000/…983d07ae9423dd57f5b3c9f92b5593d2952f1b86:3717:25)"} Error...``

Comment: It's complaining about date, message: "Match error: Expected Date", path: ""... so one of the dates is wrong format, ie the data or the createdAt

Comment: Thank you Mikkel. I have one input defined as a date, the on the client file I get the that date `data: target.data.value,`. In the other date, Is created in the server side.

Comment: I solved, doing this `data: target.data.value.toString(),` in the client side and it worked but I don't know if this will have impact in the end. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are passing object type value to your methods. You can also read the error "Match error: Expected string, got object". This is occurring by check package.

So before sending to check make sure you are sending correct type.

Once all the check are passed. You function will still have mongo error. Because you are not sending a valid object to in insert method.

```
Clientes.insert({
    nome,    //This is a string
    idade,   //This is a string
    genero,  //This is a string
    sessao,  //This is a string
    data,    //This is a date
    quemPreenche,  //This is a string
    createdAt: new Date(),  
    owner: this.userId,
    username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
});
```

So this is not a valid object. So you have to create a key value pair object. Like:

```
Clientes.insert({
    nome:nome,
    idade:idade,
    genero: genero,
    sessao:sessao,
    data:data,
    quemPreenche:quemPreenche,
    createdAt: new Date(),  
    owner: this.userId,
    username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username,
});
```

Comment: This is not the case with ES5/ES6 - you can create objects using *object shorthand*, i.e. {a,b,c} == {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}

Answer (score 0):

You initial error is pretty simple, you define you method with a parameter list of *6* individual parameters as:

```
'clientes.insert'(nome,idade,genero,sessao,data,quemPreenche)
```

But you called it from your event handler with:

```
Meteor.call('clientes.insert',{nome,idade,genero,sessao,data,quemPreenche});
```

which is only *one* parameter, an object.

Removing the braces in the call solves the initial problem:

```
Meteor.call('clientes.insert',nome,idade,genero,sessao,data,quemPreenche);
```